# Deploying nginx with docker /api

Tags: docker, nginx

How do you deploy static web with express api and mongodb?

Ive tried all different kind of ways to configure nginx but i cant get it to talk to the api at the location /api

ive tested that i can access api and mongodb with the api but i cant access the api from the nginx server http://localhost:8082/api/ gives me 404

Here is the docker-compose for the stack.

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
    js-alist-api:
        image: "js-alist-api:latest"
        ports:
          - "5005:5005"
        restart: always
        container_name: "js-alist-api"
        env_file:
          - ./server/.env
        volumes:
          - "./js-alist-data/public:/public"
          - "./server/oldDb.json:/oldDb.json"

    js-alist-client:
        image: "js-alist-client:latest"
        ports:
          - "8082:80"
        restart: always
        container_name: "js-alist-client"
        volumes:
          #- ./nginx-api.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf
          - ./nginx-api.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

    database:
        container_name: mongodb
        image: mongo:latest
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - "./js-alist-data/mongodb:/data/db"
```

Here is js-alist-client.dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./client-vue/vue/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/ # here i copy my static web

EXPOSE 80/tcp
```

next here is the nginx-api.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }


    location /api/ {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:5005/;
    
    }
}
```

If i access the http://localhost:5005 it works

If i run my api it adds data to mongodb

If i run http://localhost:8082/ i can see static web

if i run  http://localhost:8082/api or http://localhost:8082/api/ i get 404.

Also ive noticed if i change the:

```
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
```

to

```
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html2/;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
```

i still can access the static web, even if the path dont exist. That leads me to believe that the conf file is not enabled.

But i checked in the `js-alist-client` container: `/etc/nginx # cat nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

it shows that everything in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` is included

Now i dont know what is going on, and it seems my conf file is not loading. What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

After some trial and error, not sure what im doing, but i saw this line elsewhere on internet:

```
listen [::]:80;
```

Added this line and added the suggested proxy_pass to service name of the container and got it working, but only halfassed. Meaning it only goes to the root subpath of `/api`. Every other subpath such as /api/images/something/else is not working.

New nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /api/ {
     

        proxy_pass http://js-alist-api:5005/;
    
    }

}
```

How do i get that every and all subpaths are allowed?

EDIT2:

The next day i come in and now even this .conf is not working (posted in EDIT) I have no idea why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt. What a load of carp.

Answer (score 1):

In a container context, `localhost` means the container itself. So when you say `proxy_pass http://localhost:5005/;`, Nginx passes the request on to port 5005 in the client container.

Docker-compose creates a docker network where the containers can talk to each other using their service names as host names. So you need to change the `proxy_pass` statement to

```
proxy_pass http://js-alist-api:5005/;
```

Comment: does not work even with the service name of the api container. even if i put google.com it gives me 404. I get the feeling that the conf file is not working, but why?

Comment: In your post you say you checked `nginx.conf` in `/etc/nginx` with a `cat`command. Can you check `default.conf` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` instead, please?

Comment: i replace defaut.conf because its mapped in docker-compose under volume. ` - ./nginx-api.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf `

Comment: i tried to curl http://js-alist-api:5005 from within the nginx container and i got result, but cant access the api using the exposed port http://localhost:8082/api. The conf file is not working :(